# Internal Server Error: No backing RepositoryOperations configured for repository

Tags: java, maven, microservices, micronaut, backing

"I am new to micronaut assist me out here what could be the issue. I have also done the annotation processor enable on my eclipse for this project. my java version is JavaSE-1.8 and eclipse version  2021-06 (4.20.0)"
*"Internal Server Error: No backing RepositoryOperations configured for repository. Check your configuration and try again"*

**Error I am getting on console**

```
[36m14:02:58.040[0;39m [1;30m[default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-3][0;39m [1;31mERROR[0;39m [35mi.m.http.server.RouteExecutor[0;39m - Unexpected error occurred: No backing RepositoryOperations configured for repository. Check your configuration and try again
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.ConfigurationException: No backing RepositoryOperations configured for repository. Check your configuration and try again
    at io.micronaut.data.intercept.DataIntroductionAdvice.findInterceptor(DataIntroductionAdvice.java:172)
    at io.micronaut.data.intercept.DataIntroductionAdvice.intercept(DataIntroductionAdvice.java:87)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:137)
    at io.micronaut.validation.ValidatingInterceptor.intercept(ValidatingInterceptor.java:138)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:137)
    at power.microservices.res.UserRepository$Intercepted.update(Unknown Source)
    at power.microservices.res.services.UserServiceImpl.addUser(UserServiceImpl.java:39)
    at power.microservices.res.HelloController.addUser(HelloController.java:34)
    at power.microservices.res.$HelloController$Definition$Exec.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractExecutableMethodsDefinition$DispatchedExecutableMethod.invoke(AbstractExecutableMethodsDefinition.java:378)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$4.invoke(DefaultBeanContext.java:583)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.AbstractRouteMatch.execute(AbstractRouteMatch.java:303)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.RouteMatch.execute(RouteMatch.java:111)
    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestContext.with(ServerRequestContext.java:103)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.RouteExecutor.lambda$executeRoute$14(RouteExecutor.java:659)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDeferContextual.subscribe(FluxDeferContextual.java:49)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8469)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:426)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onNext(ReactorSubscriber.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:172)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler$4.doOnComplete(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:950)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.subscriber.CompletionAwareSubscriber.onComplete(CompletionAwareSubscriber.java:79)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.jackson.JsonContentProcessor$1.doOnComplete(JsonContentProcessor.java:136)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.subscriber.CompletionAwareSubscriber.onComplete(CompletionAwareSubscriber.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.processor.SingleThreadedBufferingProcessor.doOnComplete(SingleThreadedBufferingProcessor.java:48)
    at io.micronaut.jackson.core.parser.JacksonCoreProcessor.doOnComplete(JacksonCoreProcessor.java:94)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.subscriber.SingleThreadedBufferingSubscriber.onComplete(SingleThreadedBufferingSubscriber.java:71)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.jackson.JsonContentProcessor.doOnComplete(JsonContentProcessor.java:161)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.subscriber.CompletionAwareSubscriber.onComplete(CompletionAwareSubscriber.java:79)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher.publishMessage(HandlerPublisher.java:383)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher.flushBuffer(HandlerPublisher.java:470)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher.publishMessageLater(HandlerPublisher.java:360)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher.complete(HandlerPublisher.java:423)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher.handlerRemoved(HandlerPublisher.java:418)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.callHandlerRemoved(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:946)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerRemoved0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:637)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.remove(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:477)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.remove(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:423)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.removeHandlerIfActive(HttpStreamsHandler.java:483)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.handleReadHttpContent(HttpStreamsHandler.java:319)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:282)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsServerHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsServerHandler.java:134)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.channelRead(WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.channelRead(HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.java:64)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.dequeue(FlowControlHandler.java:200)
    at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.read(FlowControlHandler.java:139)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:686)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.read(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:671)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher.requestDemand(HandlerPublisher.java:165)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler$2.requestDemand(HttpStreamsHandler.java:273)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher$ChannelSubscription.receivedDemand(HandlerPublisher.java:556)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher$ChannelSubscription.lambda$request$0(HandlerPublisher.java:494)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:995)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [io.micronaut.data.operations.PrimaryRepositoryOperations] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2795)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:888)
    at io.micronaut.data.intercept.DataIntroductionAdvice.findInterceptor(DataIntroductionAdvice.java:169)
    ... 80 common frames omitted
```

**My Pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>power.microservices.res</groupId>
    <artifactId>power-microservices-res</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>${packaging}</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.4</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <jdk.version>11</jdk.version>
        <release.version>11</release.version>
        <micronaut.version>3.4.4</micronaut.version>
        <exec.mainClass>power.microservices.res.Application</exec.mainClass>
        <micronaut.runtime>netty</micronaut.runtime>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-netty</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-runtime</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-hibernate-jpa</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.micronaut.build</groupId>
                <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Uncomment to enable incremental compilation -->
                    <!-- <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation> -->

                    <annotationProcessorPaths
                        combine.children="append">
                        <path>
                            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                            <artifactId>micronaut-http-validation</artifactId>
                            <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
                            <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>3.4.1</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                            <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
                            <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                        </path>

                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=power.microservices.res</arg>
                        <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=power-microservices-res</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**My Repository file**

```
package power.microservices.res;
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.Repository;
import io.micronaut.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import power.microservices.res.models.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{}
```

**My Impl File:**

```
package power.microservices.res.services;

import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Bean;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;
import power.microservices.res.UserRepository;
import power.microservices.res.dtos.UserDTO;
import power.microservices.res.dtos.UserMapper;
import power.microservices.res.interfaces.UserService;
import power.microservices.res.models.User;

@Bean
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Inject
    private UserRepository repo;
    @Override
    public UserDTO addUser(UserDTO userDTO) {
        User saveUser = new User();
        saveUser.setName(userDTO.getName());
        saveUser.setSureName(userDTO.getSureName());
        saveUser.setEmail(userDTO.getEmail());
        saveUser.setCountry(userDTO.getCountry());
        repo.update(saveUser);//Always giving issue on this line 
    
        UserDTO userDto = new UserDTO(userDTO.getName(), userDTO.getSureName(), userDTO.getEmail(), userDTO.getCountry());
        return userDto;
    }
}
```

**My Controller**

```
package power.microservices.res;



import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.*;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;
import power.microservices.res.dtos.UserDTO;
import power.microservices.res.interfaces.UserService;
import power.microservices.res.models.User;
import power.microservices.res.services.UserServiceImpl;

@Singleton
@Controller("/hello")
public class HelloController {
    
    @Inject
    private UserServiceImpl userService;

    
    @Get(value = "/message")
    public String message() {
        return "POWER API Response";
    }

    @Put
    public HttpResponse<UserDTO> addUser(@Body UserDTO userDTO) {
        System.out.println("RESPONSE:: "+userDTO.getId()+"\n"
                    +userDTO.getName()+"\n"
                    +userDTO.getSureName()+"\n"
                    +userDTO.getEmail()+"\n"
                    +userDTO.getCountry()+"\n");
        UserDTO saveUser = userService.addUser(userDTO);
        return HttpResponse.ok(saveUser);
    }

}
```

**My yml file**

```
micronaut:
  server:
    port: 8100
  application:
    name: powerMicroservicesRes
      
datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/powerdb_reg
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: root
    schema-generate: NONE
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    

jpa:
  default:
    entity-scan:
      packages: 'power.microservices.res.models'
    properties:
      hibernate:
        bytecode:
          provider: none
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: update
        show_sql: true
        format_sql: true
        
io:
  micronaut:
    context:
      condition: trace
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the JDBC datasource pool.

Add this:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.sql</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-jdbc-hikari</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Awesome!!! This was the problem indeed !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change in your yml file.
`schema-generate: NONE` to `schema-generate: CREATE`
after that return it back to `schema-generate: NONE`

`schema-generate: CREATE` will create the database artifacts on application deployment. The artifacts will remain unchanged after application redeployment.

`schema-generate: NONE` will do no schema creation or deletion will take place.

Comment: Tried it, It seems its not related to schema-generation.